# Townhall March Meeting - suggested topics

Tags: discussion, townhall

Please add suggested topics below, and upvote the ones you wish to discuss, and downvote those which you believe do not need discussion. Remember, the top 5 ones will be raised in the townhall meeting.

Answer (score 4):

The blog for the site?  Details, how to run it, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Handling of polling questions - such as "does anyone know of..." or "has anyone got experience in..."

Answer (score 3):

Tag cleanup.

- We discussed several times whether [international-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-travel) is good for the site or not but never made a formal decision.
- The consensus was that each language should have its own tag yet [english](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) is still a synonym of [languages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages). Shouldn't we commit either way on this?
- We need to teach people that putting definitions in tag wikis is against Stack Exchange policy for common terms. For unusual terms like "ESTA" tag wikis do need definitions, for most other tags the wiki should advise users on which kinds of questions should have the tag etc. This has been covered in the Stack Exchange blog a couple of times.

... please add other tag issues you've noticed ...

Answer (score 1):

Tag naming conventions. Discussed last time, but no real result?